# Performing search in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a question in WP8 app development. 
So that's what I wanna do:

I have multiple busses routes like:

Bus 1: start's from street ... end's with street ...

Bus 2.........

I add 2 text boxes where user enter:
1. From(street name) and 2. Destination(street name)

and I need to perform a search in every bus route and show the results with wich bus user can get to destination.

the only thing I need to understand is where to save the bus route and how to perfom a search in that file or string? here's a little code:

```
 int search(string *from, string *to)
    {
    char[200]; int busnumber;
    //first compare if the from matches
    for(busnumber=1; bussnumber<10; bussnumber++)
    {
    if(stricmp(from,busnr[busnumber])==0)
       {
          if(stricmp(to,busnr[busnumber])==0)
           {
               return busnumber;
            }
        }
     }

   }
```

Comment: But how is it related exactly to wp8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your question well but here's what I can think of.
If you have data ordered in following manner:

[bus_number][start][destination]

and your data omit all the middle bus stops, then you have to simply iterate through the list.
Although if there is an option that user wants to find path to a place for which there is no direct bus, and he will have to change buses, then you have to use graph and an algorith that efficiently searches the path.
You will also have to use weighted graph if your data is as following:

[bus_number][start][busstop2][busstop3]...[busstop(n-1)][end]

and find a path with a constraint for example that you cannot have more than three buses changes.This algorithm will be a little bit complicated.